# Response to preflight request - can't see why? (CORS, fetch, PHP)

Tags: php, cors, fetch, create-react-app

I found many discussions online about this, e.g. such as [this great accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header), but still can't work out what's wrong. I've done the following:

1. Created a React app using `create-react-app`.
2. Started the server using `npm start` and can see my app in the browser.
3. Using `fetch` to contact my local server:

```
    fetch("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/endpoint.php", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: credentials.username,
        password: credentials.password
      })
    }).then(response => {
      console.log("fetch competed!");
    });
```

4. In my PHP endpoint,

```
<?php

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");

    ...
```

5. But then Chrome console debug says:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/endpoint.php' from origin 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Having done some reading, the preflight request sends an `OPTIONS` to the server, which I have allowed in the PHP header. I also tried some `proxies` in the `package.json` file and restarted the server using `npm start`.

I also tried passing through `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` and I still get an error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/php/login.php' (redirected from 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/php/login.php') from origin 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I also tried replacing my `fetch` with something simpler:

```
    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      body: new URLSearchParams("email=test@example.com&password=pw")
    });
```

but still it does not work.

I don't understand what the problem could be?

Comment: cors-anywhere does not support preflight requests

Answer (score 0):

For those facing similar problems, I managed to fix this issue by starting a separate Apache server, `systemctl start apache`, and hosting my PHP endpoints in the Apache root, e.g. `/var/www/html/public/`. For some reason the `create-react-app` development server just wouldn't work, but hosting my files on a separate local server worked fine.